# How to drop multiple tables in Big query using Wildcards TABLE_DATE_RANGE()?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I was looking at the documentation but I haven't found the way to Drop multiple tables using wild cards.

I was trying to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
DROP TABLE
 TABLE_DATE_RANGE([clients.sessions_], 
                  TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'), 
                  TIMESTAMP('2017-05-31'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used python to loop this and solve it using Graham example:

```
 from subprocess import call


   return_code = call('bq  rm -f -t dataset.' + table_name +'_'+  period + '', shell=True)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this. Better to either stay in bash, or go all in with Python.

Comment: Well, It is bit tricky because, I had to loop for certain dates and reading some info from a CSV. I just needed it for a quick fix.I couldn't make it work just using python libraries. But you are right on this. I would be better to use one or the other.Cheers

Answer (score 12):

For dataset `stats` and tables like `daily_table_20181017` keeping dates conventions, I would go with simple script and gcloud Command-Line Tool:

```
for table in `bq ls --max_results=10000000 stats |grep TABLE |grep daily_table |awk '{print $1}'`; do echo stats.$table; bq rm -f -t stats.$table; done
```

Comment: In the new `gcloud alpha bq` interface, you can do
`tables=$(gcloud --format='table[no-heading](TABLE_ID)' --project=$project alpha bq tables list --dataset=$dataset);
for table in $tables; do gcloud --project=$project alpha bq tables delete $table --dataset=$dataset; done
`
Useful if the `bq` interface stops working, like it did for me…

Answer (score 9):

DROP TABLE [table_name]; is now supported in bigquery. So here is a purely SQL/bigquery UI solution.

```
select concat("drop table ",table_schema,".",   table_name, ";" )
from <dataset-name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where table_name like "partial_table_name%"
order by table_name desc
```

**Audit** that you are dropping the correct tables. Copy and paste back into bigquery to drop listed tables.

Comment: That's an improved version of your query:

`
SELECT
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG( sqls), "; " )
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT("drop table ",table_schema,".", table_name ) AS sqls
  FROM
    <dataset-name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE
    table_name LIKE "partial_table_name%"
  ORDER BY
    table_name DESC )
`

Answer (score 4):

DDL e.g. `DROP TABLE` doesn't exist yet in BigQuery. However, I know Google are currently working on it.

In the meantime, you'll need to use the API to delete tables. For example, using the gCloud tool:

```
bq rm -f -t dataset.table
```

If you want to do bulk deletes, then you can use some bash/awk magic. Or, if you prefer, call the Rest API directly with e.g. the [Python client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026031/google-big-query-how-to-drop-table-with-bq-command) too.

Comment: I see now, I am trying to do bulk drop lots of tables. I am using: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-bigquery  with delete but it just delete the data but not the table it self

Comment: You need to use the `delete_table` method. See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#tables and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L468

Comment: I just created a python script to loop:  bq rm -f -t dataset.table  That solved for the moment cheers....

Answer (score 2):

With scripting and table information schema available, the following can also be used directly in the UI.

I would not recommend this for removing a larger number of tables.

```
FOR tn IN (SELECT table_name FROM yourDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name LIKE "filter%")
DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("DROP TABLE yourDataset.%s", tn.table_name);
END FOR;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a long time @graham's approach worked for me. Just recently the BQ CLI stopped working effectively and froze everytime I ran the above command. Hence I dug around for a new approach and used some parts of Google cloud official documentation. I followed the following approach using a Jupyter notebook.

````
from google.cloud import bigquery

# TODO(developer): Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('/folder/my_service_account_credentials.json')

dataset_id = 'project_id.dataset_id'
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_id)

# Creating a list of all tables in the above dataset
tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset))  # API request(s)


## Filtering out relevant wildcard tables to be deleted
## Mention a substring that's common in all your tables that you want to delete

tables_to_delete = ["{}.{}.{}".format(dataset.project, dataset.dataset_id, table.table_id) 
                    for table in tables if "search_sequence_" in format(table.table_id)]

for table in tables_to_delete:
    client.delete_table(table)
    print("Deleted table {}".format(table))  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

To build off of @Dengar 's answer.  You can use procedural SQL in BigQuery to run all of those delete statements in a for loop like so:

```sql
FOR record IN (
  select concat(
  "drop table ",
  table_schema,".",   table_name, ";" ) as del_stmt
from <dataset_name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
order by table_name) DO
  -- create the views
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  FORMAT( """
    %s
    """, record.del_stmt);
END
  FOR;
```

Add a WHERE condition if you do not want to delete all tables in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Dengar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867681/dengar)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70370820/12602899) and [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4202622/paul)'s reply, I used another solution. This also accounts for tables and views.

**Warning:** The resulting commands will drop ***ALL*** tables and views within the given dataset. That was my use case.

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG( sqls), "; " )
FROM (
        SELECT
            CONCAT("DROP ", ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(table_type, ' '))[OFFSET(0)], " ", table_schema,".", table_name) AS sqls
        FROM <DATASET-NAME>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY table_name DESC
     )
;
```