# BigQuery: Loop through tables in dataset and drop tables with a specific prefix

Tags: google-bigquery

Our development environment in BigQuery is isolated to a development dataset i.e. `dev` in BigQuery. The environments are further isolated by a prefix of the ticket for each table i.e. `DATA-100-change-table` would correspond to the DATA-100 ticket.

I am aware of [setting TTL for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time), however, I am also interested in having a query I could run by hand to delete the tables.

So far, I have the below:

```sql
begin
  -- Create temporary table of tables to drop from `dev` with prefix
  create temp table to_drop (drop_string STRING)
  as
  (
    select concat("drop table if exists ", table_catalog, ".", table_schema, ".", table_name)
    from dev.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where table_name like "DATA-100%"
  );

  -- Loop through table and execute drop_string statements
  for drop_statement in (select drop_string from to_drop)
  do
    execute immediate drop_statement;
  end for;
end
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
Query error: Cannot coerce expression drop_statement to type STRING at [14:23]
```

Is my approach right here? How do I best delete all tables with a prefix in BigQuery?

Also, if possible, I would like this query to handle views as well.

Comment: Hi @philMarius, can you try the solution provided in this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142613/how-to-drop-multiple-tables-in-big-query-using-wildcards-table-date-range#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20procedural%20SQL,as%20del_stmt%20from%20.). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar yep that's what I've been doing, listing tables with the first part of the transaction then dropping by hand, was wondering if there was an automated way of doing it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [p13rr0m's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7482962/p13rr0m) answer as inspiration, I've come up with the below:

```sql
begin
  create temp table to_drop (drop_string STRING)
  as 
  (
    select
      case 
        when table_type = "BASE TABLE" then concat("drop table if exists `", table_catalog, ".", table_schema, ".", table_name, "`")
        when table_type = "VIEW" then concat("drop view if exists `", table_catalog, ".", table_schema, ".", table_name, "`")
      end as drop_string
    from
      `dev.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
    where
      table_name like "DATA_100%"
  );

  for drop_statement in (select drop_string from to_drop)
  do
    execute immediate drop_statement.drop_string;
  end for;
end
```

Had to add backticks to the tables as it was failing on dropping views.

Answer (score 1):

The variable drop_statement in the for loop contains a struct. So you have to access the string with `drop_statement.drop_string`.

```sql
begin
  -- Create temporary table of tables to drop from `dev` with prefix
  create temp table to_drop (drop_string STRING)
  as
  (
    select concat("drop table if exists ", table_catalog, ".", table_schema, ".", table_name)
    from dev.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where table_name like "DATA-100%" and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  );

  -- Loop through table and execute drop_string statements
  for drop_statement in (select drop_string from to_drop)
  do
    execute immediate drop_statement.drop_string;
  end for;
end
```

To drop VIEWs, just replace `table_type = "BASE TABLE"` with `table_type = "VIEW"` and use `drop view if exists` instead.